# custom lags acf/ccf in R

Tags: r, correlation, xts

is there a way to generate a ccf plot in R using `ccf` but to allow it to only use negative lags? i tried changing `lag.max` but it still retains a symmetric shape.

EDIT: to clarify, i need lags that are larger than the standard default that gets plotted (i think the default is +-34)

Comment: From `?ccf`: the default number of lags is 10*log10(N/m) where N is the number of observations and m the number of series. The maximum number of lags is one less than the number of timepoints in the data.

Comment: so how does one change the default number of lags?

Comment: You change the number of lags with the `lag.max=200` as I do in my answer below.

Comment: ahh, i see. `lag.max` changes the number of lags but i guess the plot still defaults to whatever it does to. make sense. thanks.

Comment: Ill try to make my answer a bit clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed one of the examples in ?ccf. I created a `ccf` object then looked at its structure, I don't plot it yet by using `plot=F`:

```
>xccf=ccf(mdeaths,fdeaths,ylab="wtf!",lag.max=200, plot=F)
>str(xccf)
```

The `str` commmand shows that there is a there is component call lag that are a sequence of some sort, look at it with:

```
    > xccf$lag
, , 1

              [,1]
  [1,] -5.91666667
  [2,] -5.83333333
  [3,] -5.75000000
  [4,] -5.66666667
  [5,] -5.58333333
 ...       ...    ...
[141,]  5.75000000
[142,]  5.83333333
[143,]  5.91666667
```

The length of the lags will be the lag.max or the number of observations in the shorter data, whichever is lower.  For this example data I set max.lag to be 200 but since there is not enough data to comput that many you only get 143. If you want only the negative ones the first 71 are they. So I pass which lags into the square brackets to subset to those. Then call plot on the thing.

> plot(xccf[xccf$lag[1:71],])

which gives this plot:

[image: OOHH aahhhh!]

Comment: sorry, i should have been specific, i need lags that are outside of the standard range.. so i need more than say 34 lags or whatever it does auto